# Installing to virtual env doesn't work

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I install to virtualenv, yet it still runs the versions from C:\Python27\site-packages or C:\Python34\site-packages.  When I try to install with pip in my venv I get already installed and the location is the global site-packages.

Any idea why that could be??

Also my virtualenv wrapper commands work but when i do workon X it doesn't activate the venv.

OS is win7.  But the problem occurred on powershell and git bash.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're using the local `pip` in the `venv`?

Comment: Yes, I ensured that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems by realiasing pip and starting over and using --force-installed to install everything all over (including venv) it worked.